# rails: adding css class to a select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, actionview

How to add a css class to  a select box?

I have this code

```
<%= select_tag(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:", :class =>  "widens")) %>
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a closing parenthesis in the wrong place. You need to pass the `class` option to `select_tag`, not `options_for_select`. So you want this:

```
<%= select_tag(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:"), :class =>  "widens") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [select tag docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) you need to pass it as an options hash so this should do it:

```
<%= select_tag(:ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:"), {:class =>  "widens"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as following:

```
<%= select_tag :ptype, options_for_select(TourParticipation::PTYPES, selected: "traveler", disabled: "Role:"), {class: "widens", multiple: false, id: ""} %>
```

This is [api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) which you can references.